# How to end decimal number with .0 and .5 only using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function to calculate the duration using VB.Net.
It looks like this.

```
    Private Sub calcDuration()
        Dim startTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(timeFromPicker.Text)
        Dim endTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(timeToPicker.Text)
        Dim span As TimeSpan = endTime.Subtract(startTime)
        Dim durationTot As Decimal = 0.0
        durationTot = span.TotalHours
        lblHiddenOTDuration.Text = durationTot.ToString("N1")
    End Sub
```

So, sometimes the duration could be 2.2, 2.4, 3.6, 4.7, and etc.

I would like if the duration is less than .5, it'll become .0 .
For example, 2.2 become 2.0, 3.1 become 3.0 .

Then, if the duration is more than .5, it'll become .5. For example, 3.6 become 3.5, 4.7 become 4.5.

I'd be happy if any of you guys could help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: times 2, then round (or "floor"), then divide by 2

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you meant by that. Could you show me the way ? I'm the ' need to see a full example to learn something' type of learner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First multiply the number to "round to halves" by 2,
then perform the required rounding,
then divide by 2 to get back to the correct value.

Because you want "halves", by multiplying by 2 you get whole numbers as target, which you can easily round to in various ways. After rounding you need to undo the multiplication, by dividing by 2.

Example:

```vb
For i As Double = 2.2 To 3.3 Step 0.1
    Dim d As Double
    
    d = i * 2.0

    d = Math.Floor(d)
    'd = Math.Round(d)
    d /= 2.0

    Console.WriteLine($"{i:N1} -> {d:n1}")  
Next
```

will print this:

> 2,2 -> 2,0
> 2,3 -> 2,0
> 2,4 -> 2,0
> 2,5 -> 2,5
> 2,6 -> 2,5
> 2,7 -> 2,5
> 2,8 -> 2,5
> 2,9 -> 2,5
> 3,0 -> 3,0
> 3,1 -> 3,0
> 3,2 -> 3,0

With the `Math.Round` line enabled and the `Math.Floor` disabled, this will print

> 2,2 -> 2,0
> 2,3 -> 2,5
> 2,4 -> 2,5
> 2,5 -> 2,5
> 2,6 -> 2,5
> 2,7 -> 2,5
> 2,8 -> 3,0
> 2,9 -> 3,0
> 3,0 -> 3,0
> 3,1 -> 3,0
> 3,2 -> 3,0

So you can choose exactly how you want to round to halves.

Math.Round rounds to the nearest whole number, Math.Floor always rounds down (2.9 -> 2.0). There is also Math.Ceiling to always round up.

---

You can use this same trick for other granularities:

- If you want to round to **quarters**: multiply by 4, then round, then divide by 4.
- If you want to round to **multiples of 2**: first *divide* by 2, then round, then *multiply* by 2

Or

Comment: It works. Thank you so much, Hans ! In my case I use `Math.Floor` instead of `Math.Round`